# how to select specific field using a filter from access in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

in C# and windows Form,

I have a database like this:

[image]

and this is how I using a class put it's data into a `datagridview`:

```
    class DBConnection
{
    public static void GetList(Form2 frm2)
    {
        string DBPath = Application.StartupPath;
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+DBPath+@"\DataBase\SampleFeeds.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary", Connection);
        DataTable Dtable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(Dtable);
        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.DataSource = Dtable;
    }

}
```

and this is my form load:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBConnection.GetList(this);
    }
```

So far everything is ok.

now I have a question:

for example I have a list box `FeedSelectListBox`,
I want to when user click on a button `GrassLegumeForagebtn` my `FeedSelectListBox` fill with only all of Feed Names that are in the category of Grass / Legume Forage.

how should I do that ?

with help of Damirchi My problem solved

//-----------------

But now I have another question:
I want to when user select a feed from list box all of it's data from data base (like name, number, feed type and ,,,) put in a data grid view.

I used this code on my `SelectFeedbtn` but it doesn't work :

```
private void SelectFeedbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        string FeedSelectedID = FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID = 'FeedSelectedID'" , Connection);
        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(DTable);
        SelectedFeeddataGridView.DataSource = DTable;
    }
```

And `ValueMember` property of `FeedSelectListBox` is ID but the error is :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

I even use this query but it still doesn't work:

```
OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID =" FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue , Connection);
```

Comment: Getlist method is meant for getting a list of records or table, so dont use "frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.DataSource = Dtable;" in that method. Just return the datatable from that method and assign the datasource in formload method. So that you can also use same datatable as the source for FeedSelectListBox in the formload event itself.

Comment: Yes you are right I just wrote that to test my Connection and see if it's working or not, But my question is how to get all of name (not another field just name) of feed that are exist in a category (for example Grass/Legume Forage category).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you most set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of `FeedSelectListBox` and use this code on click event.
you can put this code on `GrassLegumeForagebtn` click event.

```
string DBPath = Application.StartupPath;
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+DBPath+@"\DataBase\SampleFeeds.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where category='Grass / Legume'", Connection);
        DataTable Dtable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(Dtable);
        frm2.FeedSelectListBox .DataSource = Dtable;
```

Comment: tnx a lot, it's working, can you explain to me what is the difference between Display Member and Value Member ? should I set them both or just one of them because in both case it working

Comment: Display Member is for user view in your case Feed Name/ Description and Value Member is for code behind operations , for example which one of item are selected, usually Value Member is Id.

Comment: tnx, Now I have another question, is it possible when user select a feed from list box all of it's data from data base (like name, number, feed type and ,,,) put in a data grid view ?

Comment: yes, you can get selected value from list box and filter by selected feed id use this query for filter '"Select * from FeedLibrary where id=" Listbox.SelectedValue;'

Comment: I use this query but it doesn't work:
OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter( ' "Select * from FeedLibrary where id =" frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue;',Connection);

the error is : Too many characters in character literal

Comment: remove ' from first and last of query OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter(  "Select * from FeedLibrary where id =" frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue,Connection);