# What's the difference between these queries?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Following [how to select specific feid using a filter from access in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422084/how-to-select-specific-feid-using-a-filter-from-access-in-c-sharp)

I have another question:

I recall this method whit a click event of `SelectFeedbtn_Click` and it works:

```
public static void GetSelectedFeed(Form2 frm2)
{
        string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary", Connection);

        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(DTable);

        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.DataSource = DTable;
}
```

but when I want to get an ID from `FeedSelectListBox` that `DisplayMember` is Feed Name / Description and `ValueMember` is ID it shows an exeption: `{"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."}`,
the query is:

```
public static void GetSelectedFeed(Form2 frm2)
{
        string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID = 'frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue'", Connection);

        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(DTable);

        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.DataSource = DTable;
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Are you getting errors or are you just not getting any results?

Comment: ID is probably numeric.  Remove the single quotes around it.  "Select * from FeedLibrary where ID = 2"

Comment: Sorry, but "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem. Do you get an error message? crash? exception? no data at all? Have you verified that there is a row in the database that has a textual id with that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, ID is an int so it should not be passed in quotes `''`. You are passing `frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue` as a string in query but you should pass its value with in the query so that it gets evaluated and your query becomes executable.

```
    OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID = "+frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue, Connection);

    OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID = "+FeedSelectedID, Connection);
```

Comment: tanks it worked, now if list box have multi Selection property, how should write a query to get all of selected value of list box?